# C++ Integer Array Palindrome Checker

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, palindrome

I used the following code for palindrome check of an integer array and used the value of variable 'declare' as check of palindrome. I used the technique that if declare is 1 at the end, array is palindrome, else not. But its not working. In the end of code, it always keeps the value of declare which was initialized, independent of rest of the code. Please Debug.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{

    int array1[3] = {0,0,1};
    int j = 2;

    cout << "Given Array is:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << array1[i];
    cout << endl;
    int determiner[3];
    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++){


        determiner[j] = array1[i];
        j -= 1;
    }
    cout << "Reversed Array is:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << determiner[i];
    cout << endl;

    int declare;
    for (int u = 0; u < 3; u++)
    {
        if (array1[u] = determiner[u])
        {
            declare = 1;
        }
        if (array1[u] != determiner[u])
        {
            declare = 0;
            break;
        }

    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << declare<< endl;

    if (declare==1)
        cout << "Given Array is Palindrome. Cheers!!!\n";
    if (declare==0)
        cout << "Emhmm! This aint Palindrome.\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are **not** a debugging service.

Comment: Note that declaring  `void main()` in global namespace is illegal in standard C++. You should use standard `int main(void)` unless you have any special reason to use non-standard declaration.

Comment: Are you sure the assignment in `if (array1[u] = determiner[u])` is what you want?

Comment: You could use an `else` statement instead of `if (array1[u] !=` since failing the first `if` means the values are not equal.

Comment: You should make `declare` as a Boolean type.  Using 1 and 0 to represent true and false is ... so .. ancient.  C++ has `bool` type.  Use it.

Comment: You don't need the `determiner` array.  Just use different indices.

Answer (score 1):

> if (array1[u] = determiner[u])

should be

> if (array1[u] == determiner[u])

Comment: Didn't notice that. Thanks a bunch, debugged :)

Comment: No problem. You can mark it as answered (or remove / etc).